# When Elastic search is needed for data analysis and costumer service

Tags: python, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I work with Python for a warehousing project. I can for example use in function, pandas contain function. Call any text mining library like fuzzy search and stemming libraries directly in my Python code. When and why I would call elastic search by Python and slow down all the search performance? Am I missing some knowledge what would be the benefit of elastic search in my case?

Is that sth for UI people or that can benefit data analyst and data scientist?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two different things, `pandas` is a data analysis and manipulation tool, `elasticsearch` is a search engine where you can perform a wide range of searchs, analysis and aggregations.

It is like comparing `pandas` to a Oracle or a PostgreSQL databases.

While in some use cases you can achieve the same end result with both, they still are different tools and have different functions.

If you need `elasticsearch` or not, and if it would improve your searchs, depend exclusively on your use case, I would recommend that you read this [link](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch) to understand a little more about the tool.

Comment: I actually know to some extent how elastic search works. I can get exactly the same results with my deployed ML algorithm with Python. I wonder for which cases does it really make sense to call elastic search library instead of ML libraries inside Python modules.

Comment: Without an example of what you are doing it is hard to tell if it would makes sense for you or not. As I said, they are two different tools that can achieve the same results in some cases, but I don't see pandas scaling out the same way that elasticsearch can, for example. If you suddenly need to analyze ten, twenty times more data, would your pipeline with python and pandas be easy to scale out to keep the performance?

Comment: You compare pandas and elasticsearch, but that is not the case in my question. I just provide an example as soon as possible and post that. That would be easier to discass over it.